# Install opencv3 on ubuntu installation without remove opencv2 package

Tags: opencv, ubuntu

I need to install opencv V3 in a ubuntu 16.04.

I have the packages libopencv-* (opencv 2.4.9) installed and lot of applications and libraries depends of it so I can't remove it.

I can make and install opencv 3.1 from git repos but my doubt is if I do that installation i will have conflicts between both version or even a posterior upgrade from opt-get will overwrite the new ones and make everything unstable.

Is there a way to have both at time, or remove 2.4.9 without uninstall all packages ho depend on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default install folder of OpenCV is `/usr/local/`. You can install OpenCV 3.1 to a separate location, say `/home/your_username/opencv_3.1` with CMake option

```
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/your_username/opencv_3.1
```

To build your project with OpenCV 3.1 using CMake, add

```
set(OpenCV_DIR /home/your_username/opencv_3.1/share/OpenCV)
```

to your `CMakeLists.txt`, after `project(projName)`. You can also link the corresponding libraries/headers manually or with IDE.

Comment: Ok, the build time is solved with this but in execution time? where the executable will look for the dynamic libraries?

Comment: Ok, everithing goes ok, even run time. No conflicts at this moment.

Comment: it should be OK at runtime since your executable is linked to the corresponding libraries.